# Python MySQL connector raise exception instead of returning empty list when result is empty

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

According to the documentation here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html, `cursor.fetchall()` returns an empty list if no more rows are available. But this does not seem to be the case when I try it. After executing a query that has no output (e.g. `INSERT`), when I do `cur.fetchall()`, instead of returning an empty list, it raises exception: `mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.`. What did I miss? Do I have to use a `try ... except` to avoid the program from crashing when there is no result set to fetch from?

Comment: Why are you executing a fetchall on an insert query?

Comment: In my program, the query is supplied by user. My program needs to execute the query and return the result back to user if there is any. I cannot determine whether there will be a result or not, so I always do a fetch after execution.